# Question on quadratic polynomials with real cofficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

Let$ P(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ be a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients. Suppose there are real number $s ≠ t$ such that $P(s) = t$ and $P(t) = s$. Prove that $ b - st$ is a root of the equation $ x^2 + ax + b - st = 0$.

Comment: Check your last equation. The one you're supposed to show holds. Looks weird, may be a mistake. Ideally you should be using Mathjax formatting.

Comment: Now it is corrected

Comment: $P(s)=t$ and $P(t)=s$ give the values of $a$ and $b$. Then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$s^2 + as + b = t$ [eq. $1$]

$t^2 + at + b = s$ [eq. $2$]

You need to show that $(b-st)^2 + a(b-st) + b-st = 0$. The $LHS$ of the latter can be factorised to $(b-st)(b-st + a + 1)$, so it suffices to show that at least one of these factors is zero.

Now take equation $1$ minus equation $2$, factorise and rearrange:

$(s+t)(s-t) + a(s-t) + (s-t) = 0$

Cancel $(s-t)$ as $s \neq t$:

$a + 1 = -(s+t)$ [eq. $3$]

Assume (for now) that neither $s$ nor $t$ is zero (this case will be handled separately). Take equation $1$ times $t$ minus equation $2$ times $s$, factorise, rearrange:

$st(s-t) + b(t-s) = (t+s)(t-s)$

Again, cancelling $(s-t)$ gives:

$b = (s+t) + st$ [eq. $4$]

Substituting the expressions in equations $3$ and $4$ into $(b-st + a + 1)$, we get:

$b - st + a + 1 = (s+t) + st - st - (s+t) = 0$, and hence the proposition is proven.

The remaining case is when exactly one of $s$ or $t$ is zero (both cannot be zero since they are unequal). Because of the symmetry between $s$ and $t$, it suffices to consider just one case. Let $s=0$. Equation $1$ yields $b=t$. Putting that into equation $2$ gives $t^2 + at + t = 0$.

Now $b-st = t$, and the expression $(b-st)^2 + a(b-st) + b-st$ reduces to $t^2 + at + t$, which we've already shown to be zero. Hence the proposition holds true in the case where one of $s$ or $t$ is zero, as well.

Comment: $(b−st)^2+a(b−st)+b−st=0$ why you used this and from where it came plz ezplain

Comment: @Ayushakj You're asked to show that $b-st$ is a root of $ x^2 + ax + b - st = 0$. So if you substitute $b-st$ into the left hand side of that quadratic you should get zero, which is what we need to prove. Replace every $x$ with $b-st$ and see what you get.

Comment: @Ayushakj I realised that I implicitly assumed that neither $s$ nor $t$ was zero when multiplying by these variables. Please see the edited proof, which plugs this gap.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the polynomial,$$P_1(x)=x^2+(a-1)x+b$$ its roots are $s$ and $t$
then by theory of roots $b=st$ or $b-st=0$ and you are asking that
$x^2+ax+b-st$ passes through origin.